# How to print the objects created last month instead of using datetime.timedelta(days=30)

Tags: django, django-models

I am making a Django app to print the expenses made **each month**

I have been searching since a long time how to **print the objects(expenses) created in a specific month**(or may be last month)
I checked across many stack overflow questions similar to this but was not able to find an appropriate answer.

Many people use

```
datetime.timedelta(days=30)
```

But how can this method be proper to print the expenses of a particular month.

I want to use a method like

```
datetime.timedelta(previous month)
```

Is there any possible way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good way to do that

First of all, in your **views.py** file :

1. Start with declaring today's date

```
    today = datetime.date.today()
```

2. You need to filter out the objects created last month (taking May month as an example here)

```
    may_month_expenses = 
    Expenses.objects.filter(created__month='05',created__year=today.year)
```

> Explanation:
>
> **Expenses** is the name of the **model**
>
> **objects.filter()** is used to print the objects which **satisfy the
> conditions in the brackets**.
>
> **created** is a **DateTimeField** in Expenses
>
> **created__month='05'** specifies that the object should have been **created
> in May(month number 5)**
>
> **created__year = today.year** is important as you want to print the objects
> created in month May of **this year(2021)** only.

This prints the objects created in month May of year 2021